# Ayuda con tabla HTML

Tags: html, tablas, html-tabla

aunque parece sencilla la solución, no logro obtener el resultado deseado. Quiero que aparezca en dos colunmas un calendaio y una tabla.

Actualmente aparece asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi es el codigo HTML:

```html
<div class="tab-content">

  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input id="dateselct" type="button" placeholder="Seleccionar Fechas" data-id="enableFunction" style="display: none">
    <div class="row">

      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-none">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width:5%">Fecha</th>
            <th style="width:6%">Disponibles</th>
            <th style="width:5%">Agendar</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tabla-disponibilad">

        </tbody>
      </table>



    </div>

  </div>
```

dateselct es el calendario, lo demas es la tabla. Deseo presentar asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco si alguien puede ayudarme.

Comment: ¿Estás usando algún plugin para el calendario?

Comment: hola @BetaM si el flatpickr